# How to manage the sequentive imports in python packages?

Tags: python, import

Let's say I have a package structure like this:

```
Package\
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    Subpackage\
        __init__.py
        module2.py
        module3.py
```

The essential point is that I want both the `module2.py` to work as a script if run from the `Package\Subpackage\` folder and `module1.py` to work as a script if run from the `Package\` folder.

In the `module2.py` I have `import` of the `module3.py` as follows:

```
import module3
```

And my `module2.py` perfectly works as a script when run from the `Package\Subpackage\` folder.

But when I try to run it from the `module1.py`, having there

```
import module2
```

I'm getting an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module3'`

I can fix this, by writing `import .module3` in the `module2.py` instead of just `import module3`. And then my `module1.py` works, correctly importing `module3` in `module2`.
BUT! Now I can't run `module2.py` as a script from the `Package\Subpackage\` folder.

**So, the question is**: How should I make those imports (`module3` from `module2` and `module2` from `module1`) to ensure that both `module1.py` and `module2.py` could work as scripts when run from their folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of resolving this (both in `module2.py`):

- Add `Package\Subpackage\` to the path manually:

```
from sys import path
path.append('absolute\\path\\to\\Package\\Subpackage')
import module3
```

Or better as suggested by @DenysGalanenko:

```
import os 
# get path to directory of the module2.py
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
from sys import path
path.append(dir_path + '\Subpackage')
import module3
```

- Use a different `import` statement for when you run `module2` as a script or when you import it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import module3
else:
    import .module3
```

I'd vote for the first solution though as it's more explicit.

(*Please let me know if that works. I don't have a way to test it ATM.*)

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much. But I think here is a bit better way: first to get the absolute path with
`import os`
`dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`
and only then do
`from sys import path`
`path.append(dir_path + '\Subpackage')`
Please edit your answer according to this (if no objections) and I'll accept it.
Слава Україні!

Comment: And please specify, that all that is done inside the `module1.py`.

Comment: Makes total sense. Thanks for the suggestion, updating the answer